# why 'df.str.split(',',expand=True)' doesn't work?

Tags: python, pandas, split

I just wanna split the geography data into latitude and longitude data using df.str.split(',').
But seemly it doesn't work.
The type of data like this：
[location](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J6Xes.png)

I process it like this:

```
data['location'] = data['location'].astype(str) 
data['location'].str.split(',' ,expand=True)
```

Then I got something below，[processed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qduD4.png)

Really confused that why the split function cannot detect the ',' and split the 'location' into two columns.

Comment: Is there a space after the comma? If so, try `split(', ')`.

Comment: Try ', ' looks like theres a space after the comma

Comment: ',  'Still doesn't work. The csv file just can be encoding using gbk not utf-8, will this contribute to this error?

Answer (score 1):

looks like there's a space in there, so using this should work:

```
data['location'].str.split(', ' ,expand=True)
```

if you want to use another approach that will only grab floats regardless of delimiter, try:

```
data.apply(lambda x: re.findall('[0-9.]+',x['location']), axis=1, result_type='expand')

df['lon'],df['lat'] = data['location'].str.findall('[0-9.]+')
```

Comment: just saw your comment about ', ' not working..hope this still helps

Comment: Still,,,,, is there anyway could run faster??? I know data.apply worked well， but a little slowly for my csv document.

Comment: could try the edit but don't know what the speed up would be if at all

Answer (score 1):

```
data['location'] = data['location'].astype(str) 

data[['lat','long']]=df['location'].str.split(',' ,expand=True)
```

If you are splitting a column into two columns, then you need to initate two columns like I have done above.

Answer (score 1):

```
    data['location'] = data['location'].astype(str) 

    data[['latitude','longitude']] = data['location'].str.split(',',expand=True)
```

Probably the space after the comma was the problem in your case.